# Not able to logout using express-session in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express-session

I am using express-session in my node.js application for authentication. The login route works fine but I am not able to logout. The session remains there in my mongodb database with a new expiration time when the logout link is clicked.

I have tried req.session.destroy() and req.session.cookie.expires = new Date().getTime() for the cookie to get expired when logout button is clicked but nothing worked.

**express-session code in index.js**

```
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'secret',
    cookie: { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 }, //if maxAge is set to anything between 1000 and 9000 the logout button works
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new mongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
}));
```

**loginUser.js**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const {
        email,
        password
    } = req.body;
    // try to find the user
    User.findOne({
        email
    }, (error, user) => {
        if (user) {
            // compare passwords.
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
                if (same) {
                    req.session.userId = user._id
                    res.redirect('/')
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/auth/login')
                }
            })
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/auth/login')
        }
    })
}
```

**storeUser.js**

```
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    User.create(req.body, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            const registrationErrors = Object.keys(error.errors).map(key => error.errors[key].message)

            req.flash('registrationErrors', registrationErrors)
            return res.redirect('/auth/register')
        }
        res.redirect('/')
    })
}
```

**auth.js**

```
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById(req.session.userId, (error, user) => {
        if (error || !user) {
            return res.redirect('/')
        }

        next()
    })
}
```

**logout.js**

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy(() => {
        res.redirect('/auth/login');
});
```

I expect the session to get destroyed and the page to be redirected to the login page. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: which mongo library are you using as session store ? connect mongo ?

Comment: you can try `req.session = null` or `req.logout();`

Comment: @Saroj yes i am using connect mongo.

Comment: @TruongDang tried but no success.

Comment: I think adding ttl would help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Comment: @Saroj still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  if(req.session) {
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 0
    delete req.session
  }
  res.redirect('/auth/login')
}
```